# How do I dual boot with existing Windows on SSD and new Ubuntu on HDD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have an SSD with Windows and two HDDs. I would like to install Ubuntu on my HDD.
However, I don't really have space on the SSD for another OS.

If I use the regular dual boot method included in the Ubuntu installer, can I simply tell it to install Ubuntu on the HDD instead, and will that work?

Also, is the Ubuntu experience on an HDD satisfactory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just connect the HDD to the computer and launch the Ubuntu installer. It will detect the drives connected to the system. If that's not the case, just launch terminal from the live mode and mount your drive.

> Also, is the Ubuntu experience on an HDD satisfactory?

The word **satisfactory** mean different things to different people. It depends on what you do with your PC. But for most cases, HDD would be far better for Ubuntu. It boots up pretty fast from an HDD.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu to an HDD will not be bad.  But it's not correct that installing Ubuntu to a HDD would perform better than being installed on a SSD.

Comment: It's probably a typo.

Comment: @Nmath, Of course, an HDD would not be as fast as an SSD. I meant that the speed of HDD would be more than enough for Ubuntu.